# Device Backs Button is closing Alert box in Worklight 6.2

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

When alert/confirm box is popped up on screen and I press device's back button, then the poped up alert/confirm box is getting close(without firing any event). How can I avoid this?

Below is the calling code:

```
**var buttons = [
                {
                    text : Messages.LBL_OK,
                    handler : doLogout
                }
              ];
showSuccess(Messages.ALERT_FILING_CONFIRMATION,buttons);**


function showSuccess(text,buttons){
    showDialog(Messages.LBL_CMN_DOALOG_SUCCESS_TITLE, text, buttons);
}

function showDialog(title,text,buttons){
    if(title == null || title == undefined){
        title = Messages.LBL_CMN_DOALOG_TITLE;
    }
    if(buttons == null || buttons == undefined){
        buttons = [
                       {
                        text : Messages.LBL_OK,
                        handler : defaultOK
                       }
                  ];
    }
    WL.SimpleDialog.show(title,text,buttons);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior in Android.

However, if you'd like to avoid this default behavior, you could use the [WL.App.overrideBackButton API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.App.html?cp=SSZH4A_6.2.0%2F10-0-0-1-2) in key locations in your code so that the button will 'do nothing'. When you're done, you can then use [WL.App.resetBackButton](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.App.html?cp=SSZH4A_6.2.0%2F10-0-0-1-2) to reset the back button's behavior back to its default state.

For example:

```
WL.App.overrideBackButton(callback);

function callback(){
 // doing nothing...
}
```

You could use the above before calling `WL.SimpleDialog.show()` and dismiss it in the dialog's button callback.